# MVC3: Batch edit attendence and pass the model to a Review Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model

I have an Index.cshtml view:

```
@model AttendenceModel
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("VisOppsummering", "Attendences", new { AttendenceModel = Model }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ClassName)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Attendences)
    <button type="submit">Next</button>
}
```

and an Editor Template Attendence.cshtml:

```
@model Attendence

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Student.Name)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Attended, true, new { id = "attendence" })
```

Teachers can check off all students that attended school and than pass on the changed model to "Review" action where they can review all the attendended and not attended students and Submit. I want to use MVC best practice for this. AttendenceModel has several properties and a generic list Attendences which is List.

I've tried following without success. Model is empty.:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Review(AttendenceModel model)
{
   if (TryUpdateModel(model))
   {
      return View(model);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following argument to your `BeginForm` helper is meaningless:

```
new { AttendenceModel = Model }
```

you cannot pass complex objects like this. Only simple scalar values. You could use hidden fields in your form for all properties that cannot be edited and visible input fields for the other. Or even better: use a view model which will contain only the properties that can be edited on the form and an additional id which will allow you to fetch the original model from the database and using the `TryUpdateModel` method update only the properties that were part of the POST request:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Review(int id)
{
    var model = Repository.GetModel(id);
    if (TryUpdateModel(model))
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    ...
}
```

as far as the view is concerned it would become:

```
@model AttendenceViewModel
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Review", "SomeControllerName"))
{
    @Html.HiddenForm(x => x.Id)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ClassName)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Attendences)
    <button type="submit">Next</button>
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! My code was actually correct. Initially I did try `@using (Html.BeginForm("Review", "Attendences", FormMethod.Post))` but model in `public ActionResult Review(AttendenceModel model)` was always empty. Reason for all my problems was actually datatables.net. They changed id's of all entries in tables and therefore corrupted my model.